# What are big companies' strategies to circumvent internet censorship?

Tags: networking, security

If a company has its office located in a country where website like google get blocked, and giving that the employees need a lot of googling to conduct their daily tasks,so do they usually have a corporate stargety to circumvent the internet censorship for employees located in that country?

Thanks.

Comment: Companies that are based in another country but have offices in those countries with internet censorship problems don't circumvent said internet censorship because their employees are subject at those offices to those censorship laws. This still isn't a good Superuser question, the current question, would lead to a fair amount of discussion or worst our opinion on the subject.

Comment: Honestly, the question reads like "Do they have a strategy for breaking the laws of the country in which the offices are based?" I don't mean to be discouraging, but companies aren't supposed to have corporate strategies to get around the laws to which they're subject, i.e. planning & defining how to do something that is clearly illegal.

Answer (score 0):

VPN. Lots of businesses will run hardware firewalls in their networks and give employees VPN access. This ties satelite offices together in on one local network. :)

Answer (score 0):

Some countries are trying to implement a choke point for all internet traffic to get filtered through one central location.

This would create a requirement where a computer is setup outside that country, probably a neighboring country which employees would RDP into and access google from outside their country's choke point.

If the country is blocking RDP at the choke point then that company may be SOL.